# unable to login : permission denied

Tags: linux

I recently created a new user on a Linux machine (Red hat). I was able to `su -` that user and it worked fine at that time. I shared the credentials with user. User reported that he is not able to login. So I tried to login to his account using PuTTY and I got permission denied error. I am able to `su -` user through root user.

Comment: Ether the user is denied through system settings (sshd config, userdb - it will help if you tell us how you created the user) or more likely he's entering the wrong password - did you try to login with the user credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Check the ownership of the user's home dir :

```
$ ls -ld /home/username
```

If a different user owns the file:

```
sudo chown root:root /

sudo chmod 755 /

sudo chown root:root /home

sudo chmod 755 /home

sudo chown -R username:username /home/username

sudo chmod 755 -R /home/username
```

Comment: You usually get a successful login with cwd as / is this case and a message of sort like "Could not chdir to home directory..."

Comment: it's only about ownershipt and permissions , look at my folders infos :
younes@emachines:~$ ls -ld /      
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Oct 12 14:33 /      
younes@emachines:~$ ls -ld /home       
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  5 23:40 /home         
younes@emachines:~$ ls -ld /home/younes       
drwxr-xr-x 10 younes younes 4096 Oct 12 14:53 /home/younes      
younes@emachines:~$     
 now try theses cmds :      
sudo chown root:root /
sudo chmod 755 /
sudo chown root:root /home
sudo chmod 755 /home
sudo chown -R username:username /home/username
sudo chmod 755 /home/username

Comment: the comment doesn't show comands well , i edited the answer :)